# Method of storing edits in the Stack Exchange Database

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, data-explorer

On Stack Exchange a minimum of 2000 reputation is necessary for your edits to get accepted automatically. If it's less than that, your edits need to be reviewed before they can come online. So I want to ask before they are accepted in what form they are stored. Also is there any place where rejected edits are stored or they are removed from the database?

Other then that I want to know whether in the PostHistory table entries corresponding to PostHistoryTypeId 4,5,6 (basically edits) only those edits are stored which are accepted?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/2bnQO

Comment: There's a table in SEDE called SuggestedEdits. Maybe they're in there.

Answer (score 3):

These are represented by entries in `SuggestedEdits` whose `ApprovalDate` and `RejectionDate` are both `NULL`.

Each not-yet-reviewed `SuggestedEdits` entry also has a corresponding `ReviewTask` where `ReviewTaskTypeId` is 1 (suggested edit) and `ReviewTaskStateId` is 1 (active). Check out [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) for a bit more info (although some of the fields do not have details there).

Either one of those tables on its own can be used to obtain a list of active suggested edit IDs, although only `SuggestedEdits` has the full details of the actual edit.

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/666330) shows the correspondence between `ReviewTaskStateId` and the null-ness of the date fields in `SuggestedEdits`.